# What is the purpose of quit channel in binarytrees_quit.go in go-tour solutions?

Tags: go

I don't quite understand the purpose of quit channel variable in binarytrees_quit.go. Or, am I missing the important point here. I can understand that receiver can send value to quit to tell the go routine to return or exit. But I don't think that it's the case here. Is it just to make sure that Walk routines stick around till Same finishes the execution? Won't go routine stick around just because channels are not buffered. Even if this is the case, that does not make any sense. Please help me to understand.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see that approached detailed in "[Go for gophers - GopherCon closing keynote - 25 April 2014 - Andrew Gerrand](http://talks.golang.org/2014/go4gophers.slide#36) "

> Stopping early
>   Add a `quit` channel to the walker so we can stop it mid-stride.

```
func walk(t *tree.Tree, ch chan int, quit chan struct{}) {
    if t.Left != nil {
        walk(t.Left, ch, quit)
    }
    select {
    case ch <- t.Value:
    // vvvvvvvvvvvv
    case <-quit:
        return
    }
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    if t.Right != nil {
        walk(t.Right, ch, quit)
    }
}
```

> Create a quit channel and pass it to each walker.
>   **By closing `quit` when the `Same` exits, any running walkers are terminated**.

```
func Same(t1, t2 *tree.Tree) bool {
    // vvvvvvvvvvvv
    quit := make(chan struct{})
    defer close(quit)
    w1, w2 := Walk(t1, quit), Walk(t2, quit)
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    for {
        v1, ok1 := <-w1
        v2, ok2 := <-w2
        if v1 != v2 || ok1 != ok2 {
            return false
        }
        if !ok1 {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Andrew adds:

> Why not just kill the goroutines?
>
> Goroutines are invisible to Go code. They can't be killed or waited on.
>   You have to build that yourself.
>
> There's a reason:
>
> **As soon as Go code knows in which thread it runs you get thread-locality.
>
>   Thread-locality defeats the concurrency model**.
>
> - Channels are just values; they fit right into the type system.
> - Goroutines are invisible to Go code; this gives you concurrency anywhere.
>
> Less is more.

Comment: Thanks! If we don't close quit then walkers will outlive the Same and eventually be terminated as soon as Main exits. Correct?

Comment: @HumbleLearner yes, everything stops when `Main()` exits.

Comment: BTW, isn't this incorrect - "w1, w2 := Walk(t1, quit), Walk(t2, quit)". Not using go routines?

Comment: @HumbleLearner the `Walk()` function (http://talks.golang.org/2014/go4gophers.slide#36) triggers a goroutine, and returns immediatly a channel. So no, it doesn't look incorrect. It is non-blocking, and return the mean to listen to the walk results.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I got confused Walk with walk (from above). I just saw the slide.

Comment: Why Println doesn't work in 'quit' case? What can I do to make it work?

Comment: @HumbleLearner which `Println`?

Comment: If I do something like 'fmt.Println("here")' just after 'case <-quit', it never prints it. Sorry, this might be a stupid question but still trying to get my head around these channels.

Comment: @HumbleLearner that might be a case where the `Stdout` isn't flush quickly enough before `Main()` exit. Could you try the same Print on `Stderr` to check if you see its output? `fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Test\n")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72347/discussion-between-humble-learner-and-vonc).

Comment: For fellows like me, don't get confused with 'quit' case. I've created a simple program explaining the concept - http://play.golang.org/p/0bSFfdJkxd. Thanks @VonC for helping me out.

Comment: @HumbleLearner Sure. Your example does show the main purpose of the quit channel as mentioned in http://talks.golang.org/2014/go4gophers.slide#36: "so we can stop it mid-stride". Good one.